# Applying CSS Class to Canvas

Tags: css, html5-canvas, css-filters

I have a lot of css filter classes that can be applied to an image using the the CSS filter. My goal is to convert the image with the filter applied to dataURL.

To do so, I'm placing the image into a canvas then saving the image after I applied the filter. Here's an example

```
  const img = this.img // my <img />
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  context.filter = 'grayscale(2)'
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
  const finalImg = canvas.toDataURL()
```

While this works fine applying a single filter, I have more than 30 filters made in my css class, and I would like to know if there's a way to apply a css class to a canvas object. Worst case scenario is for me to convert all of my filters into an array of string objects, but I'm just very curious. Thanks!

Link for reference to canvas context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D

Comment: I'm no expert but can't you just use "canvas.addClass("yourClass");"

Comment: Why would you place your image in a `canvas`?

Comment: @Levano because that's how you can apply css filters to an image and convert it to a data url.

Comment: @TimGerhard unfortunately the canvas context doesn't offer such functionality ):

Answer (score 1):

You can simply read the value returned by `getComputedStyle(canvasElement).filter` and use it as your context's `filter`.

```js
var img=new Image();img.crossOrigin=1;img.onload=draw;
img.src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg";


function draw() {
 canvas.width = this.width/4; canvas.height = this.height/4;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
 ctx.font = '15px sans-serif';
 ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

 for(var i=1; i<5; i++) {
  // set the class
  canvas.className = 'filter' + i;
  // retrieve the filter value
  ctx.filter = getComputedStyle(canvas).getPropertyValue('filter');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width/4, img.height/4);
  ctx.filter = 'none';
  ctx.fillText('filter' + i, 20, 20);
  // export
  canvas.toBlob(saveAsIMG);
 }
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width/4, img.height/4);
 ctx.fillText('canvas - no filter', 20, 20);
}
function saveAsIMG(blob) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);};
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

```css
.filter1 {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.filter2 {
  filter: grayscale(60%) brightness(120%);
}
.filter3 {
  filter: invert(70%);
}
.filter4 {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```