# DataURL of an img with CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, fabricjs

I have to apply some styles on `<img>` thanks to a CSS class.

Is it possible to get the `dataURL` of the `<img>` with the CSS style ?

```js
$(function() {
  // Original
  const imgOriginal = document.getElementById('original');
  const c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
  let ctx = c1.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(imgOriginal, 100, 100);

  // Filtered
  const imgFiltered = document.getElementById('filtered');
  const c2 = document.getElementById('c2');
  ctx = c2.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(imgFiltered, 100, 100);

  // Same dataURL :(
  console.log(c1.toDataURL(), c2.toDataURL());
  console.log(c1.toDataURL() === c2.toDataURL());
})
```

```css
.filter::before {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.filter {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: sepia(.5) hue-rotate(-30deg) saturate(1.4);
  filter: sepia(.5) hue-rotate(-30deg) saturate(1.4);
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>

  <img id="original" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Brad_Pitt_Inglorious_Basterds_Berlin_premiere.jpg/170px-Brad_Pitt_Inglorious_Basterds_Berlin_premiere.jpg">
  <canvas id="c1"></canvas>

  <img id="filtered" class="filter" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Brad_Pitt_Inglorious_Basterds_Berlin_premiere.jpg/170px-Brad_Pitt_Inglorious_Basterds_Berlin_premiere.jpg">
  <canvas id="c2"></canvas>

</div>
```

Maybe snippet is going to have a bug because of the `<canvas>` tag, the idea is there anyway.

---

**EDIT** :

If anyone has a suggestion with `SVG` or something else, I'm using [fabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/).

---

**EDIT 2 (NOT RESOLVE BUT FIND OTHER WAY)** :

1. Thanks to @KavianK. you could replicate `CSS` style with the `canvas` context, however to me it's boring because we have to store a different `callback` for each `CSS` class to get the `dataURL`. Working anyway!
2. Thanks to @Emeeus maybe a solution provide from your backend, not solution for me beacause i'm want to do this ONLY on the front-end. [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)
3. Thanks to @pegasuspect we can filter an image with `SVG`, I'm following this way and I replace [fabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/) by [svgjs](https://svgjs.dev/), this librairie can replace easly a `canvas` and it's more easier to work with `img` and I dind't need the `DataURL`  anymore !
4. Thanks to @Kaiido there is a way to take a `snapshot` of your `HTML` rendered with `CSS` style with [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/) easy to get `dataURL` with this case. Unfortunataly some `CSS` styles are not supported yet like `box-shadow` or `filter` that's why it's not a solution for me

This topic is not resolve but with `svgjs` I don't need actually work with `dataURL`.

Comment: I think it can't. since you can manipulate the pixels in the canvas, you can implement how you edit the image.

Comment: Just to understand, you want to get rid of javascript ? Or you just want the filtering to be done by css classes ? What should be modified in @kavian K. answer in order to be ok for you ?

Comment: @Mium indeed, I want to know if is it possible to do this without use the `canvas's context`. I'm trying with `SVG` at the moment maybe it's a good way : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content

Comment: Well unless your images are svg formatted, I don't think you can export the image+css into a dataUrl without going through canvas. Simply because the bitmap (what is displayed in your screen) is a rendered version, and what you can access through javascript is "raw" data, not combined nor rendered. So the best way today is to use canvas api to capture the bitmap (the rendered version). @Kavian K. answer seems a good solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291239/applying-css-class-to-canvas/49315470#49315470

Comment: @GameTag I did it with SVG, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51093284/3554534

Comment: @Kaiido hey thanks for this solution, it's good if the `CSS` class apply only a `filter` rule. If you check `.filter-helena` here : https://picturepan2.github.io/instagram.css/ . It's gonna be more complex because there are several rules to apply and also on the `:before`. Any way thanks for `getComputedStyle` method, i didn't know that

Comment: @GameTag in the case of .filter-helena, it not really a filter, but blending (which [can also be done through canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) btw, but would be more convoluted). For such complex cases, did you consider using something like [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/) ?

Comment: @Kaiido Good library but some CSS properties are not supported/limited : https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features/ like `transform` as limited and `mix-blend-mode` whose not supported yet

Answer (score 7):

`CSS` and `DOM` is a separate world from the bitmaps that are used for images and canvas. The bitmaps themselves are not affected by `CSS`, only the elements which acts as a looking-glass to the bitmap. So, CSS filters applied to the canvas will not be applied to the image that is produced. You either need to replicate the filters in canvas or rather re apply the same filters to the generated image.

**Example:**

There is a little known property on the context object, conveniently named [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter). This will apply a filter on the context it self. The filter must be set before next draw operation.

```js
var img = new Image();

img.crossOrigin = '';
img.src = document.getElementById( 'original' ).src;

img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' ),
        ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;

    // filter
    if ( typeof ctx.filter !== 'undefined' ) {
        ctx.filter = "sepia(.5) hue-rotate(-30deg) saturate(1.4)";
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    } else {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    }

    document.getElementById( 'filtered' ).src = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

```html
<img id="original" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Brad_Pitt_Inglorious_Basterds_Berlin_premiere.jpg/170px-Brad_Pitt_Inglorious_Basterds_Berlin_premiere.jpg" />
<img id="filtered" />
<canvas id="canvas" style="display: none"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey, I know about `filter()` function but I wanna to know if there is other way to do this without have to store all effects in a Javascript object. That's why I want kind of snapshot of `<img> + CSS` => `toDataUrl()`. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

## tldr;

You can do it with SVG. http://jsfiddle.net/1hambw93/91/

---

#### How to use SVG as a data Source for Images

It is explained [here quite nicely](https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg). It basically says you can use svg element in src tag of an `img`.

#### How to use filters in SVG

It is explained here quite nicely as well:  I could achieve the same filter effect with your code, using an SVG filter.

You can generate filter for svg from [this site using Sepium](https://kazzkiq.github.io/svg-color-filter/) to get the same filter as your css. You would have the following SVG so far:

```
<svg id="test">
    <image xlink:href='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Brad_Pitt_Inglorious_Basterds_Berlin_premiere.jpg/170px-Brad_Pitt_Inglorious_Basterds_Berlin_premiere.jpg'
      x="0" y="0" height="170px" width="218px" 
      filter='url(#sepium-filter)' />
    <filter id="sepium-filter">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" 
        values="1.3 -0.3 1.1   0 0 
                  0  1.3 0.2   0 0 
                  0    0 0.8 0.2 0 
                  0    0   0   1 0">
      </feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Then I used [a minimal javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30140386/3554534) to convert to base64 and write the result from the SVG to an [object](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/svgs-not-displaying-in-chrome), to display in HTML.

Comment: Thanks to this, I never manipulate `SVG` before, it's ***** powerfull, I replaced `fabricJS` with `svg.js` I'll can do what I want without a `canvas`

Comment: Nice solution @pegasuspect

Comment: @Emeeus thank you. *GameTag* yes it is. I didn’t know that either. It is you who gave me the clue but I was not sure if that was even possible! Cheers to all 

Answer (score 0):

There is 1 work around; It might work for your use case using CSS:

```
img[src^="data:image/png;"] {
  background-color: #000;
  filter: sepia(50%);
}
```

This will work for all the images URLs starting with `data:image/png`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, You need the computed image, so you need the result of the work made by the browser. To accomplish that, you could use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) specifically 
**wkhtmltoimage**. It uses Qt WebKit rendering engine (just like a browser). You have to install that in the server and run somethig like:

```
wkhtmltoimage  http://mysite/image-Plus-css-PLus-canvas.html myComputedImge.jpg
```

Where http://mysite/image-Plus-css-PLus-canvas.html is your image in the html with the css, javascript and whatever. All of this of course could be accomplished using ajax.

So, using this way you have a **.jpg** or **.png** file (myComputedImge.jpg in this case) that has all what you want computed, like a screenshot. If you want the base64 you could do the same as you do with `.toDataURL()` and the result is the base64 of the image **with** the css.

If you want to perform this using ajax, you could:

- Send a request, with the file as parameter or the remote url.
- If the file is remote the server must be able to reach it.
- In server side, you create a .html file with the image, the css and javascript or whatever you want.
- Run the code above detailed to create a .jpg or .png
- Respond the location of the file created to the ajax request.
- In the callback, you have the url of the new image with the filters computed.
- Since you have this new image in server side you could respond the base64 directly instead of the location, then in client side you don't need `.toDataURL()`.

Comment: I don't want use the backend to do this. I'll precise this on the main post. Thanks anyway to share this !

Comment: @GameTag maybe the explanation sounds a bit confusing but all of this could be resolved with a few lines of code.